# Stargazer Table from Zelig Probitgee

Tags: r, stargazer, r-zelig

I have (successfully) run a probitgee with clustered SEs in Zelig and want to get the output in a stargazer table.

```
mod1z <- zprobitgee$new()
mod1z$zelig(formula = dv ~ var1 + var2 +var3, id = "clusterid", data = df)
```

For stargazer, I use the following

```
mod1zf <- from_zelig_model(mod1z)
stargazer(mod1zf, type = "html", out = "table.html")
```

I get the error:

```
% Error: Unrecognized object type.
```

I attempted to run it with a Zelig linear model, and it works:

```
modlinear <- zls$new()
modlinear$zelig(formula = dv ~ var1 + var2 + var3, data = df)
modlinearf <- from_zelig_model(mod1z)
stargazer(mod1linearf, type = "html", out = "table.html")
```

The above yields a table of regression coefficients and SEs.

How can I get Zelig probitgee to work with Stargazer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the zelig.out model object. Type this into your console to see what it gives you:

```
la$zelig.out$z.out[[1]]
```

So your command will look like this:

```
stargazer(lm(la$zelig.out$z.out[[1]], type = "html", out = "table.html")
```